# How to Exit For Loop without going to Next

Tags: excel, vba

I have in my code a For loop that contains an If Else statement.  When the If statement is true, I want to exit the entire For loop.  There will be no further need to loop through the rest of the range.  Will "Exit For" be appropriate for this?

I was looking at the Exit statement on Microsoft's website, and according to them, Exit For continues execution with the statement immediately following the Next statement.  If this is true, Exit For won't work.  I want to proceed past the Next command.

I can take the time to test this using a numerical counter or something, but I'd rather get a quick answer, as I'm sure this is obvious to most people on here.  Thanks!

Comment: As an alternative you could always have a`if x then goto y` within the loop and have `y:` just below the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Using:

```
Sub test()

Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To 10

    If x = 2 Then
        Debug.Print "here"
        Exit For
    Else
        Debug.Print x
    End If

Next x

End Sub
```

I get:

```
1
here
```

And with this:

```
Sub test4()

Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To 10

    If x = 2 Then
        Debug.Print "here"
        Exit For
    Else
        Debug.Print x
    End If

Debug.Print "testing"

Next x

End Sub
```

I get:

```
 1 
testing
here
```

And with this:

```
Sub test4()

Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To 10

    If x = 2 Then
        Debug.Print "here"
        Exit For
        Debug.Print "after here"
    Else
        Debug.Print x
    End If

Debug.Print "testing"

Next x

End Sub
```

you get:

```
 1 
testing
here
```

Comment: I really appreciate your careful explanation!  This makes it very clear what happens in a wide variety of circumstances.  I'm going to incorporate "Debug.Print" into all my testing now, it seems very useful.  Thanks so much

Comment: @DustinBurns - no worries at all. Took me all of 3 minutes.